# How to link a globally installed node package to a project with yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have just started using yarn and I can't figure out how to link a globally installed package to a project. With npm I would just run `npm link <package-name>` but it doesn't work with yarn.
when I run `yarn link <package-name>` it gives this error: 
 
yarn link v1.22.4
error No registered package found called "express".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 1):

The link functionality is not really meant for linking global packages to a project. It is meant to link a package that you are working on to another project that you are working on. The fact, that the `npm link` command can be used to link globally installed packages to the current project is just an implementation detail of npm. From the [yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add/):

> For the vast majority of packages it is considered a bad practice to have global dependencies because they are implicit. It is much better to add all of your dependencies locally so that they are explicit and anyone else using your project gets the same set of dependencies.

So you should just add the dependencies via `yarn add <package-name>`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I know it's not something that I would do regularly but is there a way to achive the same functionality as like "npm link" with yarn.

Comment: You could just install the package globally with `yarn global add <package>` and then run yarn link in the global node_modules folder of the package(`~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/<package>`). That is probably not the intended use and may or may not work for your workflow. One other option is to just clone the source of the package to some directory and then run `yarn link` in this directory.